# How to overload button callback in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I wan't to create a dialog item, with the same look&feel ([like this one](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/open_alert_dialog_screenshot.png)) as AlertDialog, but where the button have a personalised callback.

I've tried to create an AlertDialog like that :

`AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
AlertDialog d = adb.setView(relativeLayout).create();`
[..]

```
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
                    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

[....]

```
                    d.setButton(-1, "Retour", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    d.setButton(-2, "Description",
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    browser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                    d.setButton(-3, "Video", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            browser.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            }
                    });`
```

When I click on the video button, or the description button, the dialog is automatically closed. 
I know that using a AlertDialog for this is not the best idea, but I'm don't have time to learn how to use fragments.

How could I prevent the dialog to close?

Comment: why not create a custom dialog

Comment: Because I wan't the button to have the same style as in an AlertDialog. And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure but can you delete the onClick(...) code or does it have to be there?

Comment: It does have to be here : it's the purpose to have the same button as in an AlertDialog, but which does'nt close when you hit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dismiss-on-button-press behaviour is built into the `AlertController` which implements AlertDialog (see lines 143-145 of [com.android.internal.app.AlertController](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java)). You're much better off creating your own subclass of `DialogFragment` and styling it like an `AlertDialog`.

You can find references to the relevant layouts/styles on lines 188-205 of [`AlertController`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java). I can't post a link to the folder with the resources in because I don't have enough reputation, but it's core/res/res/ in the linked repo.

Comment: So, if I can't prevent to close, I have to create my own Dialog class, isn'it?
In this case, how to put the same look and feel to Dialog ? (like on first post link)

Comment: Sadly, yes. Take a look at the lines in the file I've linked to, and then find the corresponding layouts and styles. Copying those will give you the same appearance, and then you just have to re-implement the behaviours you need. Also have a look at the [`DialogFragment` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). This will give the dialog the slight drop shadow, semi-opaque overlay and sizing like a standard `AlertDialog`, then you just have to style the stuff inside it.